# How link a local repository with some code inside to an existing Bitbucket repository -with some code inside too?

Tags: repository, bitbucket

Everything is in the title, I'm wondering how to link a local repository to a Bitbucket repository, I find nothing on Google currently,

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to [configure](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository) bitbucket?

Comment: thanks for answer, I have already configured it I want join a local repo to an existing remote repo

Comment: Do you want to set upstream? `git remote add upstream git@bitbucket.org:some-gatekeeper-maintainer/some-project.git` might help in that case!